# Why NSEnumerationReverse and not NSEnumerationForward

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, objective-c-blocks, enumeration

I was looking at looping through an array and I stumbled across this method --

```
- (void)enumerateObjectsWithOptions:(NSEnumerationOptions)opts
                         usingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block
```

NSEnumerationOptions is defined as -

```
enum {
   NSEnumerationConcurrent = (1UL << 0),
   NSEnumerationReverse = (1UL << 1),
};
typedef NSUInteger NSEnumerationOptions;
```

The description for these are taken from [NSHipster's blog post about enumeration](http://nshipster.com/enumerators/) --

> **NSEnumerationConcurrent**: *Specifies that the Block enumeration should
>   be concurrent. The order of invocation is nondeterministic and
>   undefined; this flag is a hint and may be ignored by the
>   implementation under some circumstances; the code of the Block must be
>   safe against concurrent invocation.*
>
> **NSEnumerationReverse**: *Specifies
>   that the enumeration should be performed in reverse. This option is
>   available for NSArray and NSIndexSet classes; its behavior is
>   undefined for NSDictionary and NSSet classes, or when combined with
>   the NSEnumerationConcurrent flag.*

NOW usually loops are written as -

```
for ( int i=0 ; i< count; i++ )
{
   //stuff
}
```

My question is, why does NSEnumerationReverse exist and NSEnumerationForward does not. Why did Apple think that looping in reverse would be better than looping from 1st index.

Is there a performance benefit of looping through arrays in reverse? Or do i not understand `NSEnumerationReverse` properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declared `NSEnumerationOptions` are for times when you want to use non-standard behaviour — forward iteration is the default behaviour that is automatically used **unless** you specify a different option.

To iterate forwards, simply pass `0` for the enumeration options parameter.

Note also that, since you're passing zero for the options anyway, you may as well just use the `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` method that does not accept any options, and does exactly the same thing otherwise (and is shorter to type).

Comment: When I write options enums like this in my code, I always include the standard or 'default' option, with a value of zero, at the start of the enum, so the behaviour is clear in all cases, so you could say that this is unclear API on Apple's end.

Comment: Use "enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:" instead (in this case) of passing 0 in options. 0 in options translates to Concurrent and that is perhaps not what you want to use since that means any object might return in a non-deterministic way, a.k.a. object id 1 might come before object id 0.

Comment: @AlexanderW 0 does ***not*** translate to concurrent: the value of `NSEnumerationConcurrent` is `1UL << 0`, which means ***1**, shifted left **0** bits*, resulting in a value of 1, not 0.